# C++ operator== overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

What is the differences between the following ways to overload operator== ?

```
// stroustrup way
friend bool operator== (MyClass &lhs, MyClass &rhs);
```

and

```
// as taught in other places, including caltech
bool MyClass::operator== (MyClass &rhs);
```

Which way is better?

Comment: You can find the answer to this question and many more in the [operator overloading FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) :)

Comment: The FAQ says "The binary infix comparison operators should, according to the rules of thumb, be implemented as non-member functions" but it doesn't justify why this rule exists - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719

Answer (score 14):

```
// stroustrup way
friend bool operator== (MyClass &lhs, MyClass &rhs);
```

Arguments should be `const`:

```
friend bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs);
```

This is preferred as it works when the first argument can be implicitly constructed.  For example, if `std::string` only had a member function `operator==`, then `"abc" == my_std_string` would not invoke it!  But, the non-member function can be invoked by implicitly constructing a string from "abc" (better yet in this particular case, a separate `bool operator==(const char*, const std::string&)` can be provided for performance reasons, but the point still stands - non-member functions can help ensure the operator works with the user-defined-type on either side).

Separately, implicit constructors are a bit dangerous - and you want to think hard about the convenience versus danger of using them.

Similarly, if you had `ObjectOfAnotherClassType == ObjectOfMyClassType`, and `AnotherClass` sported a casting operator such as `operator MyClass() const`, then the non-member/friend `operator==` would allow the cast to kick in and be able to do the comparison; the member `operator==` form would not.

A final point: you only need to make the non-member `operator==` a `friend` if there's no other way to access the data you need to compare.  Otherwise,  you can declare/define it outside the class, optionally `inline` if you want the implementation in a header that may be included from multiple translation units eventually linked into the same executable.  Not much harm though, and making it a `friend` is the only way to put the definition inside a class template, where you don't have to repeat the "`template <typename ...>`" stuff and parameters....

Answer (score 9):

First is external friend function (free function)

```
friend bool operator== (MyClass &lhs, MyClass &rhs);
```

Second is member function

```
bool MyClass::operator== (MyClass &rhs);
```

You should use second variant always then you can

You should use first variant in case:
1) First argument is the external (library) class

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, MyClass &m)
```

2) Operator's logic not related to your class and must be implemented separately

```
friend bool operator(const MyClass& my, const std::string& string_form)
```

(because your class can't know all about classes that may need in compare operator)

Answer (score 6):

This :

```
friend bool operator== (MyClass &lhs, MyClass &rhs);
```

is a function, which compares two objects.

This :

```
bool MyClass::operator== (MyClass &rhs);
```

is a member function.

You should use the one proposed by your coding standard, or use the one you prefer. None is better. Some people (including myself) prefer to have the comparison operator as a function, other prefer it as a member function.

By the way, the parameters should be of `const MyClass &` type.