# Explicitly allow for typecasting between primary and user defined type

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading

I have a Fraction class that I want to be able to typecast to a double.
Is there a way to write that explicitly? (Like operator overloading)

This is my constructor:

```
Fraction::Fraction(double n, double d) : numerator(n), denominator(d)
{
    if (d == 0) throw Error::DIVIDE_BY_ZERO;
}
```

When overloading operators, e.g.:

```
bool operator==(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
```

I want that overload to be able to take a `double` as well without having to write overloads with `(const Fraction&, const double)` and `(const double, const Fraction&)`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: it's not clear for me, do you want your overloading implementation of operator == to accept both `Fraction` and `double` as input?

Comment: @n.m. Thank you

Comment: @bogdantudose Yes, that was my goal. The reference solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use template specialization for this task instead of cast_operator.

```
template<typename T>
friend bool operator==(const T& left, const T& right) // member template
```

Also you should implement your operator overloading as free function (with `friend`) otherwise you cannot pass two arguments to it.

Please refer to [operator == overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070020/c-operator-overloading)